# Why does using DateTimeFormat I got failed to convert property error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to bind a date in the format dd/MM/yyyy, I have tried many things like:

Init binder

```
@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");   
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, null,  new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    }
```

DateTimeFormat annotation

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fecha;
```

Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
public class DateTimeConfig {

    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService conversionService() {
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = 
          new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);

        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setDateFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));        
        registrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

        // other desired formatters

        return conversionService;
    }
}
```

But none of above works, I always get this error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'fecha'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat @javax.persistence.Temporal java.util.Date] for value '2018-10-09'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2018-10-09" is malformed at "18-10-09"]
```

Actually my model is:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fecha;

<input name="fecha" type="date" th:value="*{fecha}" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Input provides you a date in ISO format. Ex. 2019-03-21. This is the format you should use to serialize it as Date correctly. Later you can format that Date in other way.

Comment: Can you explain better? I know the original format is 2019-03-21, but how can I format it?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing the terrible date-date classes that were supplanted years ago with their replacement, the *java.time* classes. Use only the modern classes such as `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`. Never use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I don't understand how this is a problem? If you know you get a string date like ' 2019-03-21' why don't you use the pattern "yyyy-MM-dd"  then for your formatter? Or even better `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`.

Comment: @JulianSolarte Do you want to change the format of the date in the input? If so you cannot do this because it depends on the browser. ```<input type="date">``` is a part of HTML5 spec which is very fresh. Instead, you should drop ```type=date``` in favor of ```type=text``` with some datepicking js plugin / component. Like this: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Solved, I was not using the default format to serialize the date plus not using modern classes. Thanks a lot to everyone, Michal if you want, you can reply my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Spring only accept yyyy-MM-dd format date in @DateTimeFormat tag  and you should use the new Java Time classes LocalDate.

Entity

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate fecha;
```

Thymeleaf

```
<input name="fecha" type="date" th:value="*{fecha}" class="form-control" />
```

The input can be showed in any format, in my case I'm showing the date in the format dd/MM/yyyy and then Spring automatically does the conversion to  yyyy-MM-dd